# google maps MarkerCluster for api v3

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I use [markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) and it works fine so far.

It looks like the markerclusterer combines 1 to 10 markers with the blue cluster icon, 11 to 100 with the yellow icon and over 100 with the red icon.

How can i change this? Is there a way with an option setting to change this range values? Let's say 1-5 blue icon, 5-50 yellow icon, over 50 red icon.

Comment: does your markerclusterer works well in api v3? I'm just using it in v2 and I'm little afraid of upgrade to v3, as it lacks many features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this function from the file [markerclusterer.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js)

```
    MarkerClusterer.prototype.calculator_ = function(markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var count = markers.length;
  var dv = count;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
    text: count,
    index: index
  };
};
```

This is the method that returns the marker iamge to be used depending on the number of markers. You will have to replace the current logic with the one you want to use :)

Comment: thnx that is exactly what i was looking for :)
i changed the markerclusterer to an other version:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0/docs/reference.html

here the function is called: MarkerClusterer.CALCULATOR

Comment: you're welcome! don't forget to mark the answer and accepted if it's what you were looking for ;)